# Java input char to array that is accessed from another class

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Just to be transparent, this is an assignment for a class I am taking. I don't want someone else to do this for me, I'm just asking for a little nudge in the right direction. In this assignment, I need to grade a test that the user takes. The answer key is given. The thing that I am stuck on is how to input the char values into the array Driver.setAnswerSet. I've extensively searched the material given in the class, and I have tried many different possible solutions in Eclipse to solve this problem I'm having. To be exact, I'm not sure exactly how to input the values into the array. Putting the values into a regular array that is initialized in the same class is something I can do, but the addition of calling the array is becoming the end of me here. How would I go about placing input from the user into the array in question when it's being called from the other class? The current error I have is "The method setAnswerSet(char[]) in the type SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne is not applicable for the arguments (char)." Again, all I'm asking for is a piece of advice or push in the right direction here. Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated. I also really do apologize if I'm asking what seems to be a stupid question.

This is the data class file that I have.

```
public class SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne {

    private char[] keySet = {
        'A','C','B','B','D','B','C','D','A','B',
        'C','A','B','C','A','B','A','C','A','D',
        'B','C','A','D','B'
    };

    //the answer key to be graded off of
    private char[] answerSet;
    //the answer key that is inputted by the user
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String socialNumber;
    private String phone;
    private String address;


    //the getters and setter made by Eclipse
    public char[] getKeySet() {
        return keySet;
    }
    public void setKeySet(char[] keySet) {
        this.keySet = keySet;
    }
    public char[] getAnswerSet() {
        return answerSet;
    }
    public void setAnswerSet(char[] answerSet) {
        this.answerSet = answerSet;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getSocialNumber() {
        return socialNumber;
    }
    public void setSocialNumber(String socialNumber) {
        this.socialNumber = socialNumber;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

The driver class of the project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne Driver = new SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int test = 1;
    int i;
    int score;

    while (test == 1) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Online Driving Test");
        System.out.println("To begin, enter your last name");
        Driver.setLastName(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your first name");
        Driver.setFirstName(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your SS number");
        Driver.setSocialNumber(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
        Driver.setPhone(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your address");
        Driver.setAddress(keyboard.nextLine());
        //for (i = 0; i < Driver.getKeySet().length; i++) {
        //    System.out.println(Driver.getKeySet()[i]);
        //}
        System.out.println("Driver License Test");
        System.out.println("There are 25 multiple choice questions");
        System.out.println("You have to get at least 20 questions correct to pass");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");


        // This is the area that I am having trouble with
        for (i = 0; i < Driver.getKeySet().length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            Driver.setAnswerSet(keyboard.next().charAt(0));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < Driver.getKeySet().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Driver.getAnswerSet()[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the scanner's `next()` method return? For the `Driver.setAnswerSet()` method - what is the type of the method-parameter?

Comment: Try to strip the code down to a minimum. For example, the phone number, address, social number, last name and first name are not relevant to this problem. Also, try to stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names should always start with lowercase (e.g. `Driver` should be `driver`).

Answer (score 0):

The error "The method setAnswerSet(char[]) in the type SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne is not applicable for the arguments (char)" is telling you that the setAnswerSet method is expecting an Array of characters, not a single character.  The method let's you overwrite the reference to the array with a new one you pass in.

You have two options:  Create an array filled with answers in SU2018LAB6_GradingDLTest_Wayne and "set" it as the new answerSet, or initialize answerSet in SU2018LAB6_DriverCandidate_Wayne and "get" it so you can start filling in the answers.

As it's currently written you can't just get the answerSet and update it because the array hasn't been initialized and is just a null reference.

Comment: I see what you’re saying, I think. Basically I’m trying to create a new “answerSet” in the class? The reason why I’m unable to set the values of setAnswerSet is because I’m trying to shove an entire array into a single char, and at the same time the array is null?

Comment: The setAnswerSet method does not set values within the answerSet array.  setAnswerSet is used to replace the answerSet array with an entirely different array.  It takes an array as a parameter, and assigns the array you pass it to the answerSet variable.  So one solution is to create an array, fill it with answers, and pass that array to setAnswerSet.